# converting the last word of a file into uppercase and writing the new content into a new file in Python

Tags: python, arrays, list, file-handling

Here is the code I tried!
the content in text.txt file is

**INPUT**

```
file=open('text.txt','r')
file.seek(0)
a=file.read()
Lst = a.split()
print(Lst)
length=len(Lst)
print(Lst[length-1].upper())
Lst[length-1]).upper()
print(Lst)
#------------------------------#
newfile=open("newfile.txt","w")
newfile.writelines(Lst)
newfile.close()
file.close()
```

**Output**
[screenshot of the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LUCbo.png)
as u can see the conversion of uppercase doesn't show up
and the same output gets written in newfile,

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

upper() doesn't change the element of the list, it just returns the uppercased value. To change it you must assign to the element:

```
Lst[length-1] = Lst[length-1].upper()
```

Answer (score 2):

The .upper() call doesn't change the string in place, it returns an uppercase version, so you'd need to assign it back into your array e.g.:

```
Lst[length-1] = Lst[length-1].upper()
```